# A miniscule problem with latextools (python library) when converting latex equation to svg

Tags: python, svg, latex

More specifically... I used (and a bit modified, but nothing much) the code from latextools webpage.

```
import latextools
import drawSvg as draw

def renderLatexEquation(f):
    latex_eq = latextools.render_snippet(r'$' + f + r'$', commands=[latextools.cmd.all_math])
    return latex_eq.as_svg()

d = draw.Drawing(100, 100, origin='center', displayInline=False)
d.append(draw.Circle(0, 0, 49, fill='yellow', stroke='black', stroke_width=2))
d.draw(renderLatexEquation(r'x^2'), x=0, y=0, center=True, scale=2.5)

d.saveSvg('vector.svg')
```

The result looks almost perfect, the only problem - the "x" has a tiny bit of it cut off (at the bottom). How can I fix that? Thank you for any hints!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe this isn't the best solution, but it still works.

I compiled whole pdf (using 'standalone' documentclass with border equal to 1pt) and then converted it to svg.

```
import latextools
import drawSvg as draw

def renderLatexEquation(f, border = '1pt'):
    packages = []
    commands = []
    config = latextools.DocumentConfig('standalone', ('border=' + border,))
    proj = latextools.LatexProject()
    content = latextools.BasicContent(r'$'+f+r'$')
    doc = content.as_document(path='figs/test.tex', config=config)
    doc = latextools.LatexDocument(path='figs/test.tex', config=config, contents=(content,))
    proj.add_file(doc)
    proj.write_src('.')
    proj.add_file(latextools.LatexDocument(path='main.tex', config=config, contents=doc.contents))
    pdf = proj.compile_pdf()
    # pdf.save('figs/test.pdf')
    return pdf.as_svg()

d = draw.Drawing(100, 100, origin='center', displayInline=False)
d.draw(renderLatexEquation('x^3'), x=0, y=0, center=True, scale=2.5, stroke='black')
d.saveSvg('test.svg')
```